# Proof that $(1+\epsilon)^n = O(1+n\epsilon)$

Tags: calculus, computational-complexity

How to prove that $(1+\epsilon)^n = O(1+n\epsilon)$ ?

So far I proved the following:

By the binomial, $(1+\epsilon)^n > 1+n\epsilon$

Also $\epsilon^n$ = 0 when n-> infinity.

Edit: n constant. $\epsilon$ -> 0.

Comment: what is the asymptotics? is it $n\to\infty$? $\epsilon\to 0$?

Comment: n -> infinity. $\epsilon$ is constant < 1. E.g $1/100$

Comment: I don't think that is true.. it has a component $n^2\epsilon^2$ in it..

Comment: surly this in not true suppose epsilon=x and n=2 we know O(x^2) no O(2x)

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: this is not true see my comment above test it in your case.

Answer (score -1):

$(1+\epsilon)^n=e^{n \times log(1+\epsilon)}$

$=1+n \times log(1+\epsilon)+\frac{(n \times log(1+\epsilon))^2}{2!}+...,$ Taylor series

$=1+n\epsilon+...   ,$  Please develop this serie well to see what is happening,  since $\epsilon^n\simeq0$ and $log(1+\epsilon)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\epsilon^{n+1}}{n+1}$, the result then follow:

$(1+\epsilon)^n=\circ(1+n\epsilon)$